# TFS 2010 Error: TF42004: Team Build failed to open folder

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I tried to build the project. I followed the steps mentioned in the below video till two minutes.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FriDustfTBc

After selecting "Queue New Build", I'm getting the below error.
ailed to create directory `'\\localhost\Drops\ServerBuild1\ServerBuild1_20121130.1'`.  Details: The network name cannot be found.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 as administrator. In inetpub\wwwroot folder, I created a folder called "Drops". My project is simple Hello world project. How to make the Build successful?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a share on localhost, named "Drops"?

Comment: If you use the command prompt and just do `mkdir \\localhost\Drops\ServerBuild1`, what happens.